# Visual Studio Assembly force-installs Target Framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-framework-version

I have this Assembly targeted at **.NET 3.5**. The code will work on later versions as well, but I like this to work on **Windows XP**. I mean, .NET is backwards compatible, right? I can run apps for **.NET 3.5** on **Windows 8.1**.

However, when I run my own assembly, it wants to install **.NET 3.5** first, even though I already have **4.5.1** installed.

How can I prevent installing **3.5** when something newer is already installed, while remaining **3.5** compatible?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "when I run my own assembly"? Are you *building* this assembly in Visual Studio? If so, it will need .NET 3.5 in order to know which members were available in that.

Comment: Yes, I am building this in `Visual Studio` where `.NET 3.5` is present. When I deploy this on a machine with `.NET 4.5` or `4.5.1`, it wants me to download and install `.NET 3.5` even though it should run fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The targeted `.NET` version is the only version that the app will depend upon by default. Visual Studio will not automatically add higher and backwards compatible releases.

Do this manually by adding other .NET versions to a configuration file:

1. On the Visual Studio menu bar:

   - Choose **Project**;
   - **Add New Item**;
   - Choose **General** from the left pane;
   - Choose **Application Configuration File**;
   - Name the configuration file *appName.exe.config*.
2. Add an item for every .NET version like so:

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

See [MSDN: Configure an App to Support .NET Framework 4 or 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

> The .NET Framework 4.5 and its point releases are backward-compatible with apps that were built with earlier versions of the .NET Framework. In other words, apps and components built with previous versions will work without modification on the .NET Framework 4.5. However, by default, apps run on the version of the common language runtime for which they were developed, so you may have to provide a configuration file to enable your app to run on the .NET Framework 4.5. For more information, see the Version compatibility for apps section earlier in this article.

[See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Looks like I'll be needing `appName.exe.config`. It's mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx). I'll check it out soon. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, although it's better (for bystanders and myself) if the solution is presented in the answer, not behind a few clicks.

Comment: The answer is a complex multi-step process already accessible to people who know where to look. I doubt anybody would gain anything by me embedding the whole MSDN-Topic in my answer. I feel like nudging people to the right place/right topic should be enough in this case, although I would definitely act differently on other topics.

Comment: I disagree because the answer to my specific question is actually pretty straightforward. But I'm a gentleman, so in stead of adding my own answer and accept it, I'll edit yours, add the relevant steps, and accept it. :)